# Can the same EF db context be used in consecutive calls

Tags: c#, entity-framework, dbcontext

I am working with Entity Framework inside an Azure function app and I got a `DbContext` class which initialize the db model. There is also a class called `DbManage` which is using the DbContext to perform the actual required actions on the db.

As of now, the implementation of the `DbManage` class has methods like this:

```
 public bool SomeAction(string input, MyContext dbContext = null)
 {
        if (dbContext == null)
        {
            dbContext = new MyContext();
        }

        using (dbContext)
        { 
            // ....
        }
}
```

When unit/integration tests are calling these methods, a mock object is passed to the methods and the real code pass null which makes the context instantiate every time.

The question is if I should re instantiate the db context class each time I want to have a session with the db like the code above does, or can the same object be used for all calls? If the same object can be used and I inject it with a DI, what type of lifetime should it get (singleton / scoped / transient)?

Comment: They should be transient. You cannot access it on multiple threads at the same time. They should have single purpose. As such they should be scoped to a short life cycle. https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/dbcontext-configuration/#the-dbcontext-lifetime
As from MS : "The lifetime of a DbContext begins when the instance is created and ends when the instance is disposed. A DbContext instance is designed to be used for a single unit-of-work. This means that the lifetime of a DbContext instance is usually very short."

Comment: @IAmGroot And then what about the code in case its defined as transient? Can i stop creating the context manually with new MyContext()? And can I stop putting the dbcontext var in a using scope?

Comment: I implemented Microsofts interface for `IDbContextFactory<MyContext>` on a factory class, and pass that into `DbManage` constructor. Then i can use `using (var dbContext = MyFactory.CreateDbContext())`. Swapping it out for test contexts where appropriate in the constructor rather than each method. We arent using DI from the program file though, so its not the best answer, or the one you are looking for, regarding implementation.

Comment: Is it possible you can write everything you said in an answer which includes a code example for the usage of IDbContextFactory inside the DBManage class? And how to make the factory create mock objects for tests and real objects for a real run?

Answer (score 0):

From https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/dbcontext-configuration/ :

> When concurrent access goes undetected, it can result in undefined
> behavior, application crashes and data corruption.
>
> Any code that explicitly executes multiple threads in parallel should
> ensure that DbContext instances aren't ever accessed concurrently.
>
> Using dependency injection, this can be achieved by either registering
> the context as scoped, and creating scopes (using
> IServiceScopeFactory) for each thread, or by registering the DbContext
> as transient (using the overload of AddDbContext which takes a
> ServiceLifetime parameter).

Comment: And then what about the code in case its defined as transient? Can i stop creating the context manually with new MyContext()? And can I stop putting the dbcontext var in a using scope?

Answer (score 0):

They should be Scoped. You cannot access it on multiple threads at the same time. They should have single purpose. As such they should be scoped to a short life cycle. https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/dbcontext-configuration/#the-dbcontext-lifetime As from MS :

> "The lifetime of a DbContext begins when the instance is created and
> ends when the instance is disposed. A DbContext instance is designed
> to be used for a single unit-of-work. This means that the lifetime of
> a DbContext instance is usually very short."

What we do is pass in Microsofts IDbContextFactory into our constructor.

We use Moq.Mock for testing

Our test context factory is therefore

```
internal class MockContextFactory : IDbContextFactory<MyDbContext>
{
    private Mock<MyDbContext> _mock;
    public MockContextFactory(Mock<MyDbContext> mockEntities)
    {
        _mock = mockEntities;
    }

    public MyDbContext CreateDbContext()
    {
        return _mock.Object;
    }
}
```

And our live Sql Server factory

```
public class EFContextFactory : IDbContextFactory<MyDbContext>
{
    public EFContextFactory()
    {
    }

    public MyDbContext CreateDbContext()
    {
        return new MyDbContext();
    }
}
```

Constructor for the class would be

```
public class DbManage 
{ 
    private readonly IDbContextFactory<MyDbContext> ContextFactory;

    public DbManage(IDbContextFactory<MyDbContext> contextFactory)
    { 
        ContextFactory = contextFactory;
    }

  public bool SomeAction(string input)
 {
    using (var db = ContextFactory.CreateDbContext())
    { 
        // ....
    }
 }
```

Then at some point higher up, from your test project or live project you construct your class with the relevant factory. e.g.
`new DbManage(new EFContextFactory())`

This isnt DI from the program.cs file. But does follow the kind of flow you are currently doing.

It can easily be adapted for dependancy injection using `services.AddDbContextFactory`.
The variation of it can be seen here.

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/dbcontext-configuration/#using-a-dbcontext-factory-eg-for-blazor

Comment: Transient may be overkill for this purpose. It's generally recommended to use scoped for DbContext